# Prestashop - How to get orders via API using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, prestashop

I'm trying to find some samples in Prestashop API where I can:

- Get orders
- For each order, get its details

I'm trying to implement an integration but couldn't find a simple way to do that in Ruby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty):

```
require 'httparty'

SITE_URL= 'http://example.com'
WEB_SERVICE_KEY = 'EXAMPLE'

response = HTTParty.get "#{SITE_URL}/api/orders?display=full", basic_auth: {username: WEB_SERVICE_KEY }
orders = response['prestashop']['orders']
```

Comment: @Cleyton [Using the PrestaShop Web Service](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Using+the+PrestaShop+Web+Service)